# How do you replace double quotes with a blank space? Angular

Tags: angular, replace, pipe

For example:

> asdq123""Prueba 2"

and I want

> asdq123Prueba 2

replace.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'replace'
})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): unknown {
    let newValue1
    newValue1 = value.replace('ObservacionWeb','').replace(':','').replace('{','').replace('}','').replace('\"','');


    return newValue1;
  }

}
```

Comment: blank space or just remove them ?

Comment: @selemmn sorry, just remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to pipe it for one string (as mentioned in your question), Javascript's `replaceAll` do the job:

```
const str = 'asdq123""Prueba 2"';
str.replaceAll('"', ''); // gives : asdq123Prueba 2
```

**Check [String.prototype.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).**

---

**Update:**

If you want a pipe to replace many strings, update your pipe as following:

```
transform(value: string): unknown {
    let newValue1;
    newValue1 = value
      .replace(/ObservacionWeb/g, "")
      .replace(/\:/g, "")
      .replace(/\{/g, "")
      .replace(/\}/g, "")
      .replace(/\"/g, "");

    return newValue1;
  }
```

This pipe would remove every `ObservacionWeb`, `:`, `{`, `}`, `"` found strings in a given string.
**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cnrvk5?file=src%2Fapp%2Freplace.pipe.ts)**

Comment: thanks but I am showing the data as follows {{ gestion.ObservacionWeb | replace }} and I think I can't apply your way, that's why I do it in a pipe

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a new variable, you can return the value of [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

You can refactor the multiple replace calls to a single call using a pattern with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
ObservacionWeb|[:{}"]
```

If the word ObservacionWeb should not be part of a larger word, use word boundaries `\bObservacionWeb\b`

The update code using `/g` to replace all occurrences might look like:

```
return value.replace(/ObservacionWeb|[:{}"]/g, "");
```